# Copy huge tables data from one database to another in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two database say DB_A and DB_B. In DB_A database, table having huge data (few tables are having 2 to 10 million data). I want to move the all table data from DB_A to DB_B database. Please help me on writing stored procedures to move efficiently (fast) the data from one database to another.

Comment: Copy as in thread title or Move?

Comment: Do you need to have the databases online at the time you are moving the data?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is how to handle your transaction logs. It has to write to both, but you should handle it in chunks.

So... Try something like this:

```
While exists (select * from db1.dbo.tablename)
Begin
 Delete top 100 from db1.dbo.tablename
 Output deleted.* into dbo.tablename;

 Checkpoint; 
End
```

Comment: (and have the databases in Simple Recovery Model)

Comment: You can go much higher than 100 of course. Pick something you're happy with (regarding the log size)

Answer (score 0):

No need to reinvent the wheel, have you considered using [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) in order to move your database data?

Using Transactional Replication for example, you could define a Publication of the database tables that you wish to be copied/replicated.

You can then either syncrhonize the data on an ad-hoc basis, using a Snapshot, or if you wish to keep the data up to date in "near real time" then you could use continuous replication.